# ASP defaultUrl code behind not executing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `LogIn.aspx` page which is currently set as start page for my project. I am using ASP authentication, and have a login button to enable access to the rest of the application.

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
            CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
```

My application seemed to be directing the logged in user to default.aspx which didn't actually exist in the project. I've now set the following in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Secure/Default.aspx"/>      
</authentication>
```

The Default.aspx contains the following code behind:

```
public partial class Secure_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           RoleRedirect();
        }

        public void RoleRedirect()
        {
            if (Boat_Registration.Code.utils.MembershipUtil.IsCurrentUserHarbourMaster())
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Secure/HarbourMaster/Default.aspx");
            }            
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Secure/CustomerSummary.aspx");
            }
        }
 }
```

However what is happening is, once the user logs in they are being directed to the Default.aspx, but the code behind is not firing and they are left sat on an empty page which is supposed to either re-direct them to the admin home page or regular user home page depending on their role.

Can anyone advise me why the defaultUrl I have added is not executing the code behind?

Comment: Put your redirection code in the question?

Comment: I have, its the above, the RoleRedirect() method

Comment: user goes to this page after getting authenticated?

Comment: Correct and this page should direct them to their respective 'home' pages. This works perfectly well if I click the home link on the LogIn which makes the url "http://localhost/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsecure%2fCustomerSummary.aspx" however if I click the login button from login.aspx it simply goes to the Default.aspx and does not execute the code behind leaving the user sat on a blank page which is meant only to direct them to their specific homepage based on the role

Comment: can you put your authentication code login page code where you are authenticating the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoEvent wireup was the issue in the Default.aspx page, it was set as `AutoEventWireup="false"` changing this to `true` solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like the error is in the 'Default.aspx' markup page. Check the page directive, especially the "Inherits" attribute. Should be pointing to your codebehind file.